# Refactoring a type (PointerProperty) and rename (old) data in .blend files

Tags: grease-pencil, properties, blend-files

I have a little question.

I registered this property in GreasePencil:

```
bpy.types.GreasePencil.old_property_name = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyCustomClass)
```

**I want** to refactor and **change the name of the property** (`old_property_name`) to `new_property_name`.

**The problem** is that I guess my .blend files internally have the data stored with that `old_property_name`, so when I refactor and change the name, all the **data has seem to** **disappear**. (I guess is still in the .blend file, but since now the property changed, that data related to the property is gone.

**My question** is:

Is there any way to keep that data or to point them to the new attribute?

(I'm asking since I don't want the users of my addon to loose their data just because )

Maybe I can do something like this when the addon loads?:

```
if old_property_exists:
    # point the data correctly to the new attribute
```

Or is there a way to rename it in the .blend file?

Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated :)